# Paypal Donate button

Tags: php, web-applications, paypal

If I use [paypal donate button](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) in my site, will my site get any response from paypal on successfull/failed transactions.

After the payment is completed, is it possible to redirect the user back to home page of my site?

Comment: I do know a possible issue: you did not read their [docs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index).

Comment: In expresscheckout API defining `RETURNURL` variable will redirect back to your domain. can you elaborate a little?

Comment: There is a "Create your button now" link, using which I generate the code. It does not contain any return url.

Answer (score 2):

you can direct all response from paypal about new donations to your email from step 1

**Follow the steps below and you will achieve your goal:**

**1- Go to [Paypal donation button](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside)**

[image]

**2- Finish step 1 by filling your required details and go to step 3:**

[image]

**3- check take customers to this url when they finish checkout.**

[image]

Hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

In Step 3 of the "Create your button now" link, there is a "Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout" field, which you should set appropriately.